# spark - get average of past N records excluding the current record

Tags: apache-spark

Given a Spark dataframe that I have

```
val df = Seq(
("2019-01-01",100),
("2019-01-02",101),
("2019-01-03",102),
("2019-01-04",103),
("2019-01-05",102),
("2019-01-06",99),
("2019-01-07",98),
("2019-01-08",100),
("2019-01-09",47)
).toDF("day","records")
```

I want to add a new column to this so that I get an average value of last N records on a given day. For example, if N=3, then on a given day, that value should be average of last 3 values `EXCLUDING` the current record

For example, for day `2019-01-05`, it would be `(103+102+101)/3`

How I can use efficiently use `over()` clause in order to do this in Spark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PySpark solution.

Window definition should be `3 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING` which translates to positions `(-3,-1)` with both boundaries included.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg
w = Window.orderBy(df.day)
df_with_rsum = df.withColumn("rsum_prev_3_days",avg(df.records).over(w).rowsBetween(-3, -1))
df_with_rsum.show()
```

The solution assumes there is one row per date in the dataframe without missing dates in between. If not, aggregate the rows by date before applying the window function.